# Kubernetes - how to check current domain set by --cluster-domain from pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

Kubernetes admin can use `--cluster-domain` to customize cluster domain instead of using default one: `cluster.local` [Kubelet Configs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/).

So the question is, how does an application pod check this domain in runtime?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It needs to be configured on the DNS server.

Either [kube-dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#kube-dns) or [coredns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns) (Favored on newer K8s versions)

kube-dns: it's a cli option [`--domain`](https://github.com/kubernetes/dns/blob/master/cmd/kube-dns/app/options/options.go#L148)

core-dns: you can configure the [K8s ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#configuration-of-stub-domain-and-upstream-nameserver-using-coredns)

And you see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#introduction):

> The kubelet passes DNS to each container with the --cluster-dns= flag.

If you'd like to know how a pod resolves `cluster.local` it does it through the `/etc/resolv.conf` that the kubelet mounts on every pod. The content is something like this:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search <namespace>.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local <nod-domain>
options ndots:5
```

`10.96.0.10` is your `coredns` or `kube-dns` cluster IP address.

Comment: Thanks Rico. That's not what I want though. Basically, I know that it's kubelet that configures the domain with the flag --cluster-domain=<default-local-domain>. And that <default-local-domain> is what I want to query from within a running pod.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? How does a pod know to search for `cluster.local`? Added more details let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: Yes, the replacement for the default <cluster.local>? I see from your added answer, you are implying parsing /etc/resolv.conf? is the format in /etc/resolv.conf always fixed? I can't find any spec covering that area.

Comment: Yeah, it's always there. The spec is just the linux man page :) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html.  This gets by the kubelet on every container and the values are populated depending on the configs/namespace. Unfortunately running `hostname` on the pod will only give you the pod name and the pod-name.domain. There's no k8s pod spec field that says this is the domain for this pod

Comment: Thanks Rico. It feels a bit hacky, but as long as it works. Though it would really be handy to be able to just query it like query namespace.

Comment: Yes. You can file an issue with on the Kubernetes github repo

Comment: @Rico, a related question. The nameserver in my pods' resolve.conf is not my coredns cluster IP. So it gives errors. How can I fix that? Basically where is "--cluster-dns" flag set?

Answer (score 9):

Running a DNS query against service **kubernetes.default** is a possible solution. Here is a one-liner example in shell:

```
kubectl run -it --image=ubuntu --restart=Never shell -- \
sh -c 'apt-get update > /dev/null && apt-get install -y dnsutils > /dev/null && \
nslookup kubernetes.default | grep Name | sed "s/Name:\skubernetes.default//"'
```

This will returns as last line:

```
.svc.cluster.local
```

However, I think it would be more robust to implement this algorithm in a programming language like go which have a good DNS client implemented in **net** library, here is an example you can run in a pod:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

// GetClusterDomain returns Kubernetes cluster domain, default to "cluster.local"
func getClusterDomain() string {
    apiSvc := "kubernetes.default.svc"

    cname, err := net.LookupCNAME(apiSvc)
    if err != nil {
        defaultClusterDomain := "cluster.local"
        return defaultClusterDomain
    }

    clusterDomain = strings.TrimPrefix(cname, apiSvc)
    clusterDomain = strings.TrimSuffix(clusterDomain, ".")

    return clusterDomain
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getClusterDomain())
}
```

Comment: It will not work if you have 'ndots:1'  at least. Preferably would be great to have an result of API call.

Comment: In Kubernets 'ndots' is set to 5 by default so it works fine. If 'ndots' is set to 1 Kubernetes will not be able to perform its DNS resolution for local names at all, so 'ndots:1' would break Kubernetes DNS. An API call would be convenient but it would add some dependencies between application pods and k8s and this is not recommended as a best practice. So I do not see an easy solution here and I live with technique above on our large scale production platforms: https://confluence.lsstcorp.org/display/DM/Understanding+and+managing+k8-based+deployment+of+Qserv+at+NCSA

Answer (score 3):

For the clusters which has CoreDNS, I have a command for querying the cluster domain name over CoreDNS config map `coredns` inside `kube-system` namespace. (Substitute the config map name and namespace if you use different configuration)

```bash
kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o jsonpath="{.data.Corefile}" \
  | grep ".local " \
  | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
```